# How to open multiple pop up browser windows from ActionScript?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, browser, mxml

How to open multiple pop up browser windows from ActionScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call JavasScript methods straight from ActionScript using the ExternalInterface

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

ExternalInterface.call('window.open("http://www.google.com/")');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a callLater to queue the navigateToUrl() call.

If sent all at once only the last navigateToUrl gets picked up by the screen update.  Check this link out -> http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/201/html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Book_Parts&file=passingarguments_086_12.html.